# Как очистить кэш в Instant CMS?

Tags: кэширование, instantcms

Стоит Instant CMS. Очень сильно кэшируюся скрипты. Как это можно побороть?

Comment: какие скрипты jscript ?

Answer (score 0):

если имеются ввиду jscript и css
вот решение для разработки рабочее

http://www.instantcms.ru/blogs/blog-irbis/hak-umnoe-keshirovanie-i-versionost-v-javascript-css-1-x.html

и аналогично для ветки 2
http://www.instantcms.ru/blogs/blog-irbis/hak-umnoe-keshirovanie-i-versionost-v-javascript-css-2-x.html

если имеются ввиду php скрипты то тут только настройки php opcache
к движку это отношение не имеет